# Link is still navigating even if user hasn't confirmed

Tags: jquery, html

MY question is that even though I click on the `Cancel` button in the confirmation, the link still navigates to its destination? How can I stop the link from navigating to the destination if user clicks on `cancel` in the confirmation box? I only want it to navigate if user clicks on the `OK` button:

```
<a id='teachlogout' href='./teacherlogout.php'>Logout</a>
```

```js
function logoutHandler() {
    if (confirm("You are currently creating an Assessment, are you sure you want to logout?" + "\n" + "(Your current assessment details will be lost)" + "\n")) {
        return true;
    }
}

// logout link
$('#teachlogout').click(function() {
    logoutHandler();
});
```

Comment: All answers I will upvote as all are correct when testing them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to return false to stop navigation. You can simple return what you get from confirm.

```
function logoutHandler() {
        return confirm("You are currently creating an Assessment, are you sure you want to logout?" + "\n" + "(Your current assessment details will be lost)" + "\n"))
}

$('#teachlogout').click(function() {
      return logoutHandler();
});
```

If you just have a confirm in logoutHandler then put it in click event.

```
$('#teachlogout').click(function() {
        return confirm("You are currently creating an Assessment, are you sure you want to logout?" + "\n" + "(Your current assessment details will be lost)" + "\n"))
});
```

You can use [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop navigation as well.

```
$('#teachlogout').click(function(event) {
       if(!confirm("You are currently creating an Assessment, are you sure you want to logout?" + "\n" + "(Your current assessment details will be lost)" + "\n")))
           event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: First answer gets best answer

Answer (score 8):

You need to `return false` or `event.preventDefault()` if the user cancels the `confirm`. Try this:

```
function logoutHandler() {
    return confirm("You are currently creating an Assessment, are you sure you want to logout?" + "\n" + "(Your current assessment details will be lost)" + "\n");
}

// logout link
$('#teachlogout').click(logoutHandler); 
// ^ Shorter version when you only need to call 1 function with no params
```

Or this:

```
function logoutHandler(e) {
    if (!confirm("You are currently creating an Assessment, are you sure you want to logout?" + "\n" + "(Your current assessment details will be lost)" + "\n")) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}

// logout link
$('#teachlogout').click(function(e) {
    logoutHandler(e);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your statement to:

```
return confirm("You are currently...");
```

The problem is, that you don't return false when user cancels the dialog.

Also, you don't work with the return value in your handler:

```
$('#teachlogout').click(function() {
    return logoutHandler(); // return was missing here
});
```

Comment: That still won't work, because the actual event handler function won't return anything at all.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/hWe4E/

```
function logoutHandler() {
            if (confirm("You are currently creating an Assessment, are you sure you want to logout?" + "\n" + "(Your current assessment details will be lost)" + "\n")) {
                return true;
            }

  return false;  //added
}


//you need to return the true/false
$('#teachlogout').click(function() {
      return  logoutHandler();
});
```